# What does "stale global reference" mean and how to store jobjects and pass them between threads?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I've recently started targeting API level 14 with my Android JNI application, and immediately discovered problems described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html).

Failing to solve the problem by explicitly managing local references (got local ref table overflow in the end of my experiments), I've decided to simply switch to global refs. Now I'm getting "attempt to use stale global reference" problem that isn't described in that article.

Here's what I'm trying to do: there's a single object that has a container of `jobject`s. Whenever Java calls my native method and passes a reference I need to store for later use, I create new global ref to that `jobject`, add global ref to the container and also store its index. Whenever I need to use the `jobject` I get it by index. What is the problem with this approach?

P. S. Whenever I call JNI methods, I am using correct `JNIEnv` for the calling thread. The thread making JNI calls is attached to JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failing to solve the problem by explicitly managing local references (got local ref table overflow in the end of my experiments)

I smell deeper problems in your code. Local ref table overflow simply cannot happen if you are aware of all local refs you are creating and deleting them properly, manually, earlier than returning from the current JNI call. The local ref creation [might be very subtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109497/android-jni-error-app-bug-local-reference-table-overflow-max-512), it's not just `FindClass`.

Anyway, if you want to make it working with global refs (which seems like the right thing to do anyway, given the usage scenario you described) i suspect this: your "container" needs those stored refs to be also removed sometimes, not just added i guess. Are you sure that you are removing the right ones, and calling `DeleteGlobalRef` on the right ones, not some others which stay in the container? Put it another way, for each `NewGlobalRef` you have in your code, make sure that you know where is the relevant `DeleteGlobalRef` and that you are confident about when and why it's being called.

Comment: Indeed, local ref table overflow was a result of my trying to build a system for abstracting the rest of code from managing local references. My idea was not thought out properly, so I've just decided it should be easier with global references.

Comment: And so far it seems that you're right and `stale global reference` means I was trying to access a reference for which I already called `DeleteGlobalRef`. I need more time to clean up and debug the code to be certain, though.

Comment: It should be that, yes. I might have written it more clearly, but i wanted to give deeper idea about WHY it's happening, not only WHAT. But if your code has been invalidated by Dalvik changed internal representation of opaque handles (which your code should be insensible to), then you surely need some cleaning up :)

Comment: That's exactly what happened. I thought my code was clean and correct in regards to reference management, I was aware of the general principle, but it took the new checks in Dalvik VM to prove me wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Have your Java methods pass a reference to the containing jobject to every native method. That way it is always automatically correct and doesn't need to be made into a `GlobalRef` at all, so you won't get local variable table overflows, have to worry about `DeleteGlobalRef()`, etc at all.

Comment: It wouldn't work for me 100%, there is stuff that I create within native methods. But thanks for the tip, I've just realized I probably shouldn't create global references to objects that were passed from Java methods as argument to native methods.