# Appcelerator Android Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople() jni error local reference table overflow

Tags: android, overflow, contacts, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

My App reads out the contacts on a phone with Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople(). On iOS everything works fine, on android it works fine until the number of contacts is at about 400. If you start the app with more than 500 contacts, it crashes with the following error:

```
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98] local reference table dump:
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]   Last 10 entries (of 510):
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       509: 0x23182b80 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       508: 0x23182b20 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       507: 0x23182ac0 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       506: 0x23182a60 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       505: 0x23182a00 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       504: 0x231829a0 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       503: 0x23182940 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       502: 0x231828e0 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       501: 0x23182880 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       500: 0x23182820 ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]   Summary:
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]         1 of ti.modules.titanium.ui.WindowProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]       508 of ti.modules.titanium.contacts.PersonProxy (508 unique instances)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]         1 of org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.ActivityProxy
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98]
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] Runtime aborting...
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] Aborting thread:
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] "KrollRuntimeThread" prio=5 tid=15 Runnable
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c07460 self=0xf3fa0400
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | sysTid=2001 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf3c56580
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | state=R schedstat=( 370171847 41934738 232 ) utm=26 stm=10 core=1 HZ=100
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | stack=0xe27ac000-0xe27ae000 stackSize=1052KB
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #00 pc 00005d03  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+83)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #01 pc 00003051  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+33)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #02 pc 003c9b97  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+135)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #03 pc 00392f52  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+306)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #04 pc 00377674  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+644)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #0
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #06 pc 000ec704  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1876)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #07 pc 00224429  /system/lib/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::Add(unsigned int, art::mirror::Object*)+1065)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #08 pc 002cb4e8  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+392)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #09 pc 00087517  /data/app/co.rittler.invitepro-1/lib/x86/libkroll-v8.so (titanium::TypeConverter::jsValueToJavaString(_JNIEnv*, v8::Handle<v8::Value>)+103)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #10 pc 0011c323  /data/app/co.rittler.invitepro-1/lib/x86/libkroll-v8.so (titanium::app::PropertiesModule::hasProperty(v8::Arguments const&)+691)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #11 pc 000a93d2   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #12 pc 0004ea24   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #13 pc 000b5fea   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #14 pc 000b102e   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #15 pc 00003b40   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #16 pc 0001eafc   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #17 pc 0001f163   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #18 pc 00003b40   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #19 pc 00017bf1   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #20 pc 00008c29   (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #21 pc 002a5b70  /data/app/co.rittler.invitepro-1/lib/x86/libkroll-v8.so (???)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #22 pc 68ffffff  ???
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeFireEvent(Native method)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.fireEvent(V8Object.java:62)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.doFireEvent(KrollProxy.java:908)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1131)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at org.appcelerator.titaniu
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:112)
[INFO] :   art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock
```

Error appears when compiling with 5.1.2GA, but i also tried 5.1.0GA and 5.0.1GA.

Can anybody help? Is there a workaround to read the contacts properly?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

In Titanium Appcelerator world, when your application is launched, a JavaScript execution environment is created in native code, and your application source code is evaluated. Injected into the JavaScript runtime environment of your application is what we call “proxy” objects – basically, a JavaScript object which has a paired object in native code. Colloquially we will often refer to “JavaScript land” and “native land” in a Titanium application, as they are kind of parallel universes to one another. The proxy object exists both in JavaScript land and native land, and serves as the “bridge” between the two. Now look at the below code sampals.

```
for(i = 0; i<$.tableSection.rowCount; i++){
     $.tableSection.rows[i].children[1].image = "/myimage.png";
     $.tableSection.rows[i].children[0].color = '#fff';
     $.tableSection.rows[i].backgroundColor = '#000';
}
```

And

```
var rows = $.tableSection.rows;
for(i = 0; i<$.tableSection.rowCount; i++){
     rows[i].children[1].image = "/myimage.png";
     rows[i].children[0].color = '#fff';
     rows[i].backgroundColor = '#000';
}
```

Now in the first one assigning property value like above cross bridge. It creates some kind of reference at native land, which do not get destroyed automatically on native land. So the native throw error. Similar example of reference table overflow is in [Android : JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109497/android-jni-error-app-bug-local-reference-table-overflow-max-512). And the second code reduces the number of reference on native land. So the recommand would be that. For more here is the referance http://jaljale.com/blog/titanium-appcelerator-crossing-the-bridge-dalvikvm-jni-error-app-bug-local-reference-table-overflow-max-512/

Comment: Yes, I found this article but my problem is that Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople() is an appcelerator function, so I can't influence if it crosses the bridge, isn't it?

Comment: I would tell you to create a JIRA ticket in https://jira.appcelerator.org/ since this is a bug, but there is already an open ticket about the issue https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-15765 follow the ticket for any update.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug tracked here:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20279